# Google maps returns non english address

Tags: java, android, google-maps, google-api, google-geocoder

I'm writing an android application which uses geocoder, in order to get an address by longitude and latitude points. I'm getting the address with both English and Hebrew even though I'm using:

```
Geocoder geocoder = new Geocoder(this, Locale.ENGLISH);
```

Here is my code:

```
    String a="";
    Double longi = Double.valueOf(nz.substring(0, 9)).doubleValue();
    Double lati = Double.valueOf(nz.substring(10, nz.length())).doubleValue();

    Geocoder geocoder = new Geocoder(this, Locale.ENGLISH);
    try 
    {
        List<Address> addresses = geocoder.getFromLocation(longi, lati, 10);

        for (Address address : addresses) 
        {
            String tmp=address.getAddressLine(0);
            if (!(tmp.contains("District")))
            {
                if (!(tmp.contains("Israel")))
                {
                    a=a.concat(tmp);
                    a=a.concat(" ");
                }
            }
            Log.d("aa","address= " + address.getAddressLine(0));
        }
        Log.d("aa","a= " + a);

    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.e("LocateMe", "Could not get Geocoder data", e);
    }
    return a;
```

Does anyone know how to solve this?

Thanx in advance